# Does PHP use a FIPS-140 compliant RNG to generate session IDs?

Tags: php, security, session, cryptography, fips

A requirement for the deployment of a PHP application I am working on is that is uses FIPS-140 validated cryptographic modules.

The customer has specifically flagged up that "PHP utilizes a cryptographically weak random number generator to produce session ID information" and cited this report: http://berlin.ccc.de/~andreas/php-entropy-advisory.txt

I have advised them on how to set session.entropy_length and session.hash_function to increase entropy, but they have not accepted this, specifically requiring that we use a FIPS-140 compliant RNG.

I'm not certain on the difference between the hash function and the RNG, so am struggling to respond. Can anyone suggest a way of using a FIPS-140 compliant function to generate session ids within php?

We're running PHP 5.4.16 on Windows + SQL Server, in case it matters.

Thanks

Comment: Newer PHP will use `/dev/*random` on UNIX-ish systems by default, as per the [session.entropy_file](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file) setting. You would have to check your OS documentation to see what the OS is doing in the background to supply that entropy.

Comment: So when the customer refers to PHP's "cryptographically weak random number generator", are they just talking about the default one, and does changing the entropy_file change the random number generator implicitly?

Comment: of course it does. if php was set for /dev/urandom and you change it to use /dev/somethingelse, you'll get a different RNG. Exactly what that RNG is doing in the background depends entirely on the implementation. I have no idea if (say) Linux's /dev/urandom is fips-compliant, or has even been submitted for testing. that's somethign you'd have to dig into the kernel source for.

Comment: Great, thanks. I queried it only because that was the answer I gave to the customer originally, and they seemed to doubt that setting the entropy source was the same as defining a different RNG. Thanks again. :)

Comment: And keep in mind that Windows does not provide the `/dev/*random` devices. If its a "out of the box" installation with no additional hardware or libraries, then they must use [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or other approved generator (I'm not sure what they are under CryptoNG).

Comment: The "cryptographically weak random number generator" refers to `rand()` and `mt_rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

> A requirement for the deployment of a PHP application I am working on is that is uses FIPS-140 validated cryptographic modules.

My condolences. A headache is to FIPS-140 what a drop of morning dew is to the ocean.

> I'm not certain on the difference between the hash function and the RNG, so am struggling to respond. Can anyone suggest a way of using a FIPS-140 compliant function to generate session ids within php?

If you're using ext/mcrypt, `mcrypt_create_iv()` uses Windows' CryptGenRandom API which *should* be FIPS-140 compliant. (Or, at minumum, it should be possible to setup that way.) That function is the only good thing about mcrypt, and exists separatef from libmcrypt.

If you're using OpenSSL, and compiled OpenSSL in FIPS mode, you can similarly use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` and it should use a FIPS-compliant generator.

Finally, if you upgrade to PHP 7+ and use `random_bytes()`, so long as Windows is FIPS-140 compliant, you're golden.

The hash function really doesn't matter here. You want to use a secure source and that's it. Hashing it doesn't buy you anything. If you're forced to use a hash function, use one of the SHA2 family hash functions (SHA256, SHA384, or SHA512) approved for use in FIPS-140 compliant software.

#### Session Generator that should pass FIPS-140 audits

```
<?php
/**
 * @return string
 */
function session_id_fips140()
{
    if (is_callable('random_bytes')) {
        return session_id(bin2hex(random_bytes(32)));
    }
    if (is_callable('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        return session_id(bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));
    }
    if (is_callable('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return session_id(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)));
    }

    // Fail closed. Maybe install random_compat?
    throw new Exception("No suitable PRNG is available on the current system!");
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.
if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_id_fips140();
}
session_start();
```